# C# ShowDialog calling another ShowDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not sure if this is allowed but I have a main form that calls another form with ShowDialog which attempts to call another form the same.

So, for example:

form1 -> form2.showdialog -> form3.showdialog

I am getting an error at the showdialog of form3:

```
var ssscu = new SSS.SssTwainSimple.MainForm();
ssscu.ShowDialog();
```

This is the error:

> {"Form showDialog tried to set an
>   ineligible form as its owner. Forms
>   cannot own themselves or their
>   owners.\r\nParameter name: owner"}

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is, am I not allowed to call a showdialog from a form that is a dialog?

Thanks,
Eroc

Comment: Add MDI allowing parent child forms?

Comment: This was caused since the ssscu form was passing itself to another form as the owner in the load... I moved the pass and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> am I not allowed to call a showdialog from a form that is a dialog?

You certainly are allowed, this ought to work.

But I do think it is strange that you create a dialog-form called MainForm.

I expect it is something caused by other stuff happening in events. What does mainForm do in it's constructor/Load-event ?

Comment: This was the issue, the programmer had the calling project doing something in the load. +1 !! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It is a very unusual exception.  The form already has an owner when it got created by the constructor.  You didn't use the ShowDialog(owner) override so Windows Forms has to find an owner for itself.  It finds the exact same form back.  That's technically possible, but you'd have to write some fairly odd code.  To diagnose this, add this code to the form:

```
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }
```

And set a breakpoint on it.  If my guess is correct, this will break *before* the ShowDialog call.  Look at the call stack to see what statement is getting that window created.

Comment: +1 since it was true... the application being called was at fault. The name is mainform since the wpf control that is calling it is in one project and the winform that is being called is another project, both in the same solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try replace `.ShowDialog();` with `.ShowDialog(this);`

**Edit:** I have not tried myself, but this is where I would start looking.